# AWS MQTT Websocket, authenticated access being restricted

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, authentication, websocket, mqtt

I'm currently working on an AWS mobile app project in Android Studio, and I'm currently trying to set up a MQTT-connection to AWS IoT through AWS Cognito & IAM authentication.

If I run the MQTT-client as a stand-alone project without authentication, assuming an unauthenticated IAM role, I'm able to connect to MQTT, and subscribe & recieve from the given topic.

However, once I try to run my MQTT-client through an authenticated user (through a log-in on my mobile app), the client is restricted, and constantly tries to reconnect.

I enabled logging in AWS CloudWatch, and the following debug message is given:
"... EVENT:MQTT Client Connect MESSAGE:Connect Status: AUTHORIZATION_ERROR"

The unauth and auth roles in the IAM console have identical policies & resource access, yet something's stopping the MQTT connection.

PS. The Auth role can, in my app, access userfiles & S3, the probelem seems to be unique for IoT access.

Does anyone know if it's possible to allow connections through an authorized user without using cert-files, if so, how? Unless I'm mistaken Cognito and IAM should be able to perform the required authorization to access resources (and it does, as long as I'm not logged in to the auth role)

Appreciate any tips I can get at this point, been struggling for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually figured out the issue by reading the AWS documentation more thoroughly.

The AWS credentials provider does not store the required information to authorize access through AWS. So I solved the issue by retreiving the required user tokens into a hash, and setting these to the credentials provider, and the issue was finally solved.

```
AuthenticationResultType authenticationResultType = new AuthenticationResultType();
    String idToken = authenticationResultType.getIdToken();


    // Initialize the AWS Cognito credentials provider
    credentialsProvider = new CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider(
            getApplicationContext(),
            COGNITO_POOL_ID,
            MY_REGION
    );

    Map<String, String> logins = new HashMap<String, String>();
    logins.put("yourAWSEndpoint", idToken);
    credentialsProvider.setLogins(logins);
```

Comment: Can you please be more specific on how you solved this issue?